# How we use this condition: $0\leq \theta F(t)<t f(t), \forall t>0~\text{where}~ F(t)=\int_0^t f(\xi)d\xi.$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I found thi inequality in a paper :

From $(f_2):$ There exists $\theta>p$ such that $$0\leq \theta F(t)<t f(t), \forall t>0~\text{where}~ F(t)=\int_0^t f(\xi)d\xi.$$
we have $$\displaystyle \frac{f(t_{R_n}a)}{(t_{R_n}a)^{p-1}}\rightarrow \infty$$ such that $R_{n}\rightarrow\infty$ with $t_{R_n}\rightarrow\infty$ and $a$ is a constant.

We have also that $2\leq p$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a function of $C^1$ class.

I don't understand how condition $(f_2)$ is used to btain that $\displaystyle \frac{f(t_{R_n}a)}{(t_{R_n}a)^{p-1}}\rightarrow \infty$

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The condition $0\leq \theta F(t)<t f(t) = tF'(t)$ can be written as
$$ 0< \frac{\theta}{t} < \frac{F'(t)}{F(t)}.$$
Integrating both sides from $t_0$ to $t$, we get 
$$ \theta \log \frac{t}{t_0} < \log \frac{F(t)}{F(t_0)},\qquad t>t_0>0,$$
or equivalently
$$ F(t) > \frac{F(t_0)}{t_0^\theta} t^\theta.$$
Therefore,
$$ \frac{f(t_{R_n}a)}{(t_{R_n}a)^{p-1}} > \theta \frac{F(t_{R_n}a)}{(t_{R_n}a)^p}
>\theta  \frac{F(t_0)}{t_0^\theta}(t_{R_n}a)^{\theta-p} \to\infty $$
as $t_{R_n}$ goes to infinity.

So you actually use the condition twice: the first time to get a differential inequality, and then in the final step.